# SoundManager API phonegap setVolume not working on iOS

Tags: cordova, soundmanager2

I am using SoundManager API on my cordova project. On Android everything is working perfectly, while on iOS the only problem is that I cannot control the volume. 
To change the volume I am using soundManager.setVolume.

Do you know a workaround to make it work in iOS ?
Is there any plugin to control iOS volume ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The volume on iOS is always under the users control and can't be set via JavaScript ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html))

> On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.